# Generating different operators from an eigenfunction and a lowest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Given an eigenfunction, $f(x)$, and its corresponding lowest eigenvalue, $\lambda$, how could one generate at least 2 different operators, $\mathbf{T_1}$ and $\mathbf{T_2}$ that both satisfies the equations below?

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{T_1}[f(x)] &= \lambda f(x) \\
\mathbf{T_2}[f(x)] &= \lambda f(x).
\end{align}
$$

**My attempt**

If it is a vector-matrix operation, I can do it by generating $n-1$ other orthogonal vectors (and arrange them horizontally to make a matrix $\mathbf{Q}$) and higher eigenvalues (and arrange them diagoally to make a matrix $\mathbf{\Lambda_i}$ and the operators are just

$$
\mathbf{T_i} = \mathbf{Q\Lambda_iQ^{-1}}.
$$

However, I am not sure on how to do the same for function because the number of elements in the function is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $(T_1 - T_2)f(x) = 0$, so first find an operator $S$ which sends $f(x)$ to zero. Once you have this, find an operator $T_1$ which has an eigenfunction $f(x)$ with lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then you can derive $T_2 = T_1 - S$.

Comment: How do we know $\lambda$ is also the lowest eigenvalue of $T_2$?

Comment: Have a think about this